# Is it possible to send alerts from many applications to many applications in Java?

Tags: java

I have two applications.
First one creates typical files.
Second application uses these files.
When first application change some file, the second application should be noted about this.
I tried to do this with ServerSocket and it does work.
First application is a client (`java.net.Socket`) and second is a server (`java.net.ServerSocket`).
But it should work also for multiple instances of applications.
In case we have multiple instances of application two, the first should alert each one.

Both application are desktop application running on same machine without any databases. The question is how to implement it and not on actual code. The actual code runs OK. It just don't fit the specifications.

Comment: Put some code effort..u may be required to use RMI..

Comment: Are they all Web Applications?

Comment: If it's only files a `Watcher` might do the trick. Besides that: yes it is possible. Just requires some work ... by you.

Comment: Without knowing your code, I think that you can also work with multicast groups. See [this](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/MulticastSocket.html) for more infos

Comment: every client application who wants to be notified on change should connect to server, then keep connected clients ip address list in server code and notify them all on any change by server application via sending udp packetds you don't need to establish tcp connection for each client or if you dont want to implement this logic look java rmi or similar apis

Comment: Which kind of application are talking about? What is running the applications?

Comment: Would this be an option? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousFileChannel.html  + https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

Comment: There are so many different options here and yet we know so little about the actual requirements. What are the nature of your applications? Web apps? Desktop? How are they separated? Two wars on the same server instance? Two desktop apps running on different networks? Are there any common resources already accessed by both apps? Maybe a common database for both?

Answer (score 1):

For understanding the problem lets take one example.

There is one application which is producing some thing lets call it as prodApp and there are many other applications which should get notified lets call them as consApp1 ,consApp2,...consAppN

Solution to this problem can be designed using the **JMS** (**Java Messaging Service**).

JMS provide the way by which multiple consApp can register at one place (which is called as **TOPIC in JMS**) and they got notified as soon as some thing has been put on TOPIC (which in this case will be done by prodApp).

So it will work like this prodApp will do its processing writes its status on JMS TOPIC as a result of this all the consApp will get notified and start there own processing.

Comment: Thanks. One more question. How it will work if we start multiple prodApp?

Comment: In case there are multiple prodApp, then all of them can write there status on JMS TOPIC. The TOPIC will contain different status that can be read by all  consApps. This scenario can be seen as many to many communication and if some one wants to have one to one communication then use another data structure given by JMS API and known as QUEUE.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've looked to http://activemq.apache.org/how-does-a-queue-compare-to-a-topic.html . And I think I'll go with TOPIC.

Answer (score 0):

In case the number of files is small and they are known to be saved in a single place, the second application[s] could check the files periodically (like every minute) for the last modification time of each file.

This could be even faster than socket, RMI or other network communications.

Comment: Sorry, this is not a solution. The user has the right to decide where to place these files. Thanks anyway.

Comment: It still could be possible if you know where the files are.